# node-mysql Using array in query

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, escaping

I'm trying do a query using an array but having a parse error.

**a** - contains an array

Ex:[ 7, 26, 87, 65, 86, 23, 63, 69, 44, 61, 8, 79, 47, 88, 15, 17 ]

**conexao_bd.escape(a)** - escaped array

Ex: 7, 26, 87, 65, 86, 23, 63, 69, 44, 61, 8, 79, 47, 88, 15, 17

It needs to be in this format  (7, 26, 87, 65, 86, 23, 63, 69, 44, 61, 8, 79, 47, 88, 15, 17), so I can use it in the query. Any help how to change format?

**Code**

```
conexao_bd.query("SELECT question, answer FROM ", conexao_bd.escape(tipo) + " WHERE id IN " + conexao_bd.escape(a) ,function(err, rows){

    if(err) console.log("Erro na query questions: "+err);
    else{
        perguntas.questions.push(rows);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(perguntas));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error on query

```
conexao_bd.query("SELECT question, answer FROM ",
```

should be

```
conexao_bd.query("SELECT question, answer FROM "+
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into Array.join() to return it as a string.  This is a basic javascript question, not node related.

Comment: But I don't want a string... It needs to be something like this (12,2,14) so I can use it in a query:
`SELECT question,answer FROM Game where ID in (12,2,14);`

Comment: You want a string, what do you think the query string is?  It's a string.

WHERE id IN (" + conexao_bd.escape(a).join(", ") + ") ...."

Comment: You can't use join after escape. After you use escape on array it's no longer an array.

Comment: Docs say "Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'", so maybe all you are missing are the parentheses.

Comment: Array.prototype.join()
Joins all elements of an array into a string.
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: I was referring to the node-mysql docs on how arrays are escaped.

Comment: Ok.

    conexao_bd.escape(a) returns a string "40, 39, 26, 16, 17, 51, 4, 23, 21"
    console.log(c) returns "(19, 35, 87, 39, 50, 14, 63, 58, 63)"


But It isn't working yet...
[code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ac534cf9ad81ebb7641)

Answer (score 2):

I Actually found the correct Answer including Escaping (to prevent SQL Injection):

> Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g. [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] turns into ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')

so the correct way:

```
conexao_bd.query("SELECT question, answer FROM ? WHERE id IN ?",[tipo,[a]],function(err, rows){

  if(err) 
     console.log("Erro na query questions: "+err);
  else{
    perguntas.questions.push(rows);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(perguntas));
 }
});
```