# Select value from table where it is not in a given list

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to get all values from a specific column in MySQL, except those I specify to ignore. In straight up SQL it's working for me with

```
SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN ('admin', 'anonymous');
+-----------------+
| login           |
+-----------------+
| testUser1       |
| testUser2       |
| testUser3       |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but I can't find the correct way to do this using [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

```
var whiteList = ['admin', 'anonymous'];
connection.query('SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN ?)', whiteList, 
  function(err, rows) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(rows);    
});
```

I have also tried writing the array explicity

```
connection.query('SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN ("admin", "anonymous")', 
  function(err, rows) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(rows);    
});
```

Either way I get the following error

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''admin')' 
at line 1
```

### Update with Fix for Hard Coded Attempt

So it turns out I made a stupid mistake with the hardcoded node version(thanks for pointing it out Jens). I had quoted it incorrectly, the following works

```
connection.query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN ('admin', 'anonymous')", 
      function(err, rows) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(rows);    
    });
```

but I still can't get it to work by passing in an array, now I am trying

```
var whiteList = ['admin', 'anonymous'];
whiteList = '(' + whiteList.join(', ') + ')';
connection.query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN ?", [whiteList], 
function(err, rows) {
      if (err) throw err;
   });
```

### Update with Answer

Turned out to be a simple fix. I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828406/node-mysql-using-array-in-query) that **Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'** so I just needed to include parentheses around the `?` placeholder as follows

```
var whiteList = ['admin', 'anonymous'];
connection.query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login NOT IN (?)", [whiteList], 
    function(err, rows) {
          if (err) throw err;
       });
```

Comment: use single quotes arround your strings and souble quoutes arround your statements.

Comment: Bloody hell, that was a bad oversight from me! Thanks. Could you suggest how I pass them in as an array, rather than writing them out one by one?

Comment: Think you need a two dimansional Array.

Comment: Normally MySQL doesn't care about quote style unless you tell it to, setting things like [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).